# Add binding to amq-direct

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm trying to create a new binding using the Rabbit Web UI, under the "exchange" tab.

The destination field (above routing key) required. However, any name I choose is not valid. It says "no queue xyz found in /".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a queue named xyz in your "/" virtual host ?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create the queue to be able to bind it with an exchange.

- Go to the Queue tab
- Create a queue
- Then bind the queue to the exchange or do as you are trying to do now

You can also anagrammatically create a queue and bind it to an exchange, in Java its done like this:

```
//Declare queue
 inChannel.queueDeclare(queue, durable, exclusive, autoDelete, arguments);
//Bind it to an exchange
inChannel.queueBind(queue, exchange, routingKey);
```

This it explained in great detail in the [tutorials](http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) using your favourite language. (if its: Ruby, Java, Python or PHP)